# Why do we need to consider the area under Volume axis to find the work done by a gas?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, work, integration, volume

For a $P$ vs $V$ graph for gas, why do we need to consider the area under the volume axis for determining the work done by the gas? Can't we take the area under the pressure axis to find the work done?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than giving a formal explanation – which I expect you will get in other answers – I ask you to consider two extreme cases ...

(1) A cylinder fitted with a movable piston contains a vapour in equilibrium with its liquid. The vapour is allowed to expand slowly, from volume $V$ to volume $V+\Delta V$, at constant temperature, so that the pressure, $p$, stays constant. So a p–V graph is a horizontal line. The area 'under' the pressure axis is zero. But how much work is done on the piston by the vapour? [Remember: Work done by gas = Force on piston $\times$ outward distance moved by piston = pressure $\times$ volume increase of gas. (If the pressure changes as the volume changes we calculate the work for such small increases in volume that the pressure hardly changes – and then add all the bits of work together. Integration!)]

(2) A gas is kept in a cylinder with a piston locked in place. The gas is heated so that the pressure rises from $p$ to $p+\Delta p$. The volume doesn't change, so the p–V graph is a vertical line. What is the area 'under' the pressure axis? How much work is done on the piston?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do something similar, but not precisely how you suggest.

The key concept to bear in mind is that expressing work $W$ as
$$
W = -\int p dV
$$
is the integration of the *differential form* $-pdV$ along a path in the state-variables space.

In general, if we have a differential form in a $N$-dimensional space
$$
df = \sum_i f_i(x_1,\dots,x_N)dx_i
$$
the integral of $df$ along the path $\gamma$ parametrized by the functions
$
x_i(\lambda)
$, $\lambda \in [0,1]$, where $x_i(0)$ is the starting point and $x_i(1)$ the end point of the path $\gamma$, is defined as
$$
I= \int_0^1 d \lambda \sum_i f_i(x_1(\lambda),\dots,x_N(\lambda))\frac{d x_i}{d \lambda}.
$$
It can be shown that the integral value is independent of the parametrization.

The consequence for thermodynamics is that we are not obliged to integrate $p$ as a function of the volume. However, it is not true that a change of parametrization implies looking for the area **below the same curve**.

An example may help to clarify the issue.
Let's consider an isotherm $p(V)=\alpha V^2$ from a volume $V_1$ to a volume $V_2$.
Here, the paramter $\lambda$ coincides with $V$ and the integral of our form is simply
$$
W=\int_{V_1}^{V_2}p(V)dV = \int_{V_1}^{V_2}\alpha V^2 dV = \frac{\alpha}{3} \left( V_2^3 -  V_1^3  \right).
$$
In the present case, the function $p(V)$ is invertible and we can use $p$ to parametrize the same path, without need of splitting the integral into more integrals:
$$
V = V(p) = \left( \frac{p}{\alpha} \right)^{\frac12},
$$
with initial and final points at $p_1=\alpha V_1^2$ and $p_2=\alpha V_2^2$.
In the present case the integral to evaluate is:
$$
W=\int_{p_1}^{p_2} p \frac{dV}{dp} dp = \frac{1}{2 \alpha^\frac12} \int_{p_1}^{p_2}p^{\frac12}dp = \frac{1}{3 \alpha^\frac12} \left( p_2^{\frac32} - p_1^{\frac32} \right) = \frac{\alpha}{3} \left( V_2^3 -  V_1^3  \right).
$$

Notice that there are cases where the observation that we are integrating a differential form is crucial. For example, in order to find the chemical potential difference between liquid and vapor in the case of a gas obeying van der Waals equation of state, one has to integrate $V dp$ along an isotherm. If we do not interpret the integral as the integral of a differential form, we would be in big troubles because below the critical point the isotherms $p(V)$ are not invertible. The problem disappears if we integrate the differential form $Vdp$ along the isotherm.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do we need to consider the area under Volume axis to find the work
> done by a gas?

Because the work done on or by the gas for a closed system is boundary work, i.e., the work done in expanding or contracting the boundary (volume) of the system (gas).

Start with the basic definition of work

$$dW=\vec F\cdot d\vec x$$

$$W=\int_1^2\vec F\cdot d\vec x\tag{1}$$

consider a cylinder fitted with a piston of cross sectional area $A$. A differential change in volume due to a displacement of the piston of $dx$ is

$$dV=Adx$$

$$dx=\frac{dV}{A}\tag{2}$$

The pressure $P$ of exerted on the piston  is

$$P=\frac{F}{A}$$
$$F=PA\tag{3}$$

Substituting (2) and (3) into (1)

$$W=\int_1^2 PA\frac{dV}{A}=\int_1^2 PdV$$

> Can't we take the area under the pressure axis to find the work done?

I assume you mean taking the area under the process using a $VP$ diagram where pressure is the x-axis rather than the usual $PV$ diagram where volume is the x-axis. If we do this for an isobaric (constant pressure) expansion process the area under the pressure axis would equal zero, for no work done. Which, of course, would be incorrect.

Hope this helps.